# Can I return multi value in emacs org src code?

Tags: org-mode, python

As follow code,can I get a list for other code block?

```
#+name: test
#+BEGIN_SRC python -n  :exports both
for i in range(5):
    return i
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: test
: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just return a list.

```
#+name: test
#+begin_src python -n
retval = []
for i in range(5):
    retval.append(i)
return retval
#+end_src

#+begin_src python -n :var x=test
retval = []
for j in x:
    retval.append(j+42)
return retval
#+end_src
```

BTW you could return a list more directly without using a loop like e.g.

```
#+name: testb
#+begin_src python -n
return [1, 2, 3, 1000]
#+end_src
```